# Curvature in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

Let $f(t) = (x(t),y(t))$, not necessarily parametrized by arclength.

We define the unit tangent vector, $T(t) = (1/|f'(t)|)(x',y')$. Also the normal vector, $N(t) = (1/|f'(t)|)(-y',x')$, which is defined this way so that the rotation $T \rightarrow N$ is done anti-clockwise.

Since $T'$ and $N$ generate the same vector space we then define the curvature , for each $t$, as the only scalar $k(t)$ such that $T'(t) = k(t)N(t)$.

Since $|N(t)| = 1$ then we get $k(t) = T'|N$, where | is the dot product.

After computing $T'$ and that dot product i get

$k(t) = (1/(|f'(t)|^2 )) (x'y''-x''y')$

when it is supposed to be

$k(t) = (1/(|f'(t)|^3 )) (x'y''-x''y')$.

Anyone familiar with these formulae?

details:

$T(t)=(1/|f'(t)|)(x',y')$.

$T'=[\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(1/|f'(t)|)](x',y')+(1/|f'(t)|)(x'',y'')$

Since the first vector of the sum above is orthogonal to $N(t)$ then its dot product is $0$.

So $$T'|N = [(1/|f'(t)|)(x'',y'')] | N = [(1/|f'(t)|)(x'',y'')] | [(1/|f'(t)|)(-y',x')] = (1/(|f'(t)|^2 )) (x'y''-x''y')$$

Comment: thanks for the formatting Nicolas! (only the " ^ " symbol is missing, i'm talkin about the powers of |f'(t)| )

Answer (score 0):

Here how I get the formula :

We have
$$T\left(t\right)=\frac{\left(x',y'\right)}{\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}}$$ and then the velocity (the norm of $T$) is given by
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\mathrm{d}t}=\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}.$$
Hence, we can compute :
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}T}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(t\right)
=\frac{\left(x'',y''\right)}{\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}}-\frac{1}{2}\left(x',y'\right)\frac{2x'x''+2y'y''}{\left(x'^2+y'^2\right)^{3/2}}
=\left(x''y'-x'y''\right)\frac{\left(y',-x'\right)}{\left(x'^2+y'^2\right)^{3/2}},$$
$$k\left(t\right)=\left\Vert\frac{\mathrm{d}T}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}s}\right\Vert 
=\left|x''y'-x'y''\right|\frac{\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}}{\left(x'^2+y'^2\right)^{3/2}}\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}}
=\frac{\left|x''y'-x'y''\right|}{\left(x'^2+y'^2\right)^{3/2}}.$$

Comment: well i guess we now have 2 different definitions, and three different formulas, for the curvature in R^2.

Comment: I edited my post : the final result was not correct. Now I am sure with my answer. Note that you must have a non-negative curvature, hence you need the (non-negative) term $|x''y'-x'y''|$ in the formula for $k$.

Comment: the way i'm working with curvature in R^2 it can be negative. The inverted parabola (t,-t^2), for example, has negative curvature in (0,0).

Comment: Ok, well forget my last comment about the non-negativity!

Comment: yeah i guess there's no consensus on R^2 curvature. in R^3, however, is it always positive...

Comment: Indeed : it is just a matter of definition. Do not put the absolute values for the last calculus for $k$ to get the formula you were looking for. :-)